# Prevent a form from coming to the front

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two TopMost forms quite close together (form A and B). If I click on A it comes to the front and put's itself over form B. I tried to overwrite the WndProc method:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
     if (m.Msg == 0x0201 || m.Msg == 0x0202 || m.Msg == 0x0203)
     {
         return;
     }

     base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Nevertheless the form A still overlays form B if I click on it so I guess it must be some other Msg code. Hopefully someone knows how to do it.

Comment: Is form A a child of form B? I can't tell if you want B to modal, of if a MDI child situation would work.

Comment: No it's not a child modal is not the way to do this.

Comment: So you always want B in front of A but you want to interact with A when it has focus?

Comment: To be honest I don't want to interact with any of these forms, it's just that B always has to be in front of A. The problem is the user might click on one of these by accident. I could use Enable = false but then I get this annoying Ding sound. Ah and please don't tell me anything about bad UI design that's what my client wants.

Comment: Can you sent the Form.TopMost property on B and not on A? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx

Comment: Would love to flag this as the answer. Write one and I'll flag it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you have BringToFront/BringToBack functions available under ActiveForm. I suggest you look into those. Off the top of my head, I'd probably override one of those and make sure when Form A has focus, to bring form B to front.

However, the problem you're having can be solved without code.